# Network issues in Windows 7

Tags: networking, windows-7

We recently upgraded a dozen of PCs to new hardware and Windows 7 professional (before we had XP), but we are experiencing many newtwork issues, for example SSH sessions (using Putty) stops working after a while.

Checking the LAN with various testing tools doesn't report any issue.
We have no XP PCs anymore for testing, but a pair of MACs do work fine.

I wonder if this is a known Windows 7 issue, and how can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling TCP receive window autotuning:

```
netsh interface tcp set global autotuning=disabled
```